# Behaviour of a function in two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is a bit of a soft question. Suppose we consider a function $f\,\colon\,\Omega \to \mathbb{R}_+$, where

$$
\Omega := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\;|\; x,y \geq 1\},
$$
for which it is known that for $x,y$ large enough there exist positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that

$$
\text{(1) }f(x,y) \leq C_1 x^{-3}y^{-1}\quad\text{ and }\quad \text{(2) }f(x,y) \leq C_2 x^{-1}y^{-3}.
$$

My initial silly intuition was that this in fact implies that for $x,y$ large enough there exists $C_3>0$ such that

$$
\text{(3) }f(x,y) \leq C_3 x^{-3}y^{-3}. 
$$
It's clear that (3) implies both (1) and (2), but what about the other way round? It's definitely safe to divide (1) and (2) by 2 and add them up to conclude that there exists $C_4>0$ such that for $x,y$ large enough we have

$$
\text{(4) }f(x,y) \leq C_4\left(x^{-3}y^{-1} + x^{-1}y^{-3}\right) =:g(x,y). 
$$
But then $g$ satisfies neither (1) nor (2) and so statement (4) is weaker than (1)&(2).

Can you please tell me whether (1)&(2)  implies (3) and if not then why (and ideally an example of a function $f$)? Also, if (3) is not true then can we somehow improve on (4)?

This seemed trivial and silly at first but the more I think about the more confused I am. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: The biggest function that satisfies (1) and (2) (for $C_1 = C_2 = 1$) is $\min(x^{-3}y^{-1}, x^{-1}y^{-3})$.  Now check that for $x = y$ you don't have hope of satisfying (3) for any constant.